# Symfony2 Select one column in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to refine the query trying to select fewer possible values ​​..
For example I have an entity "Anagrafic" that contains your name, address, city, etc.,
and a form where I want to change only one of these fields, such as address.
I have created this query:

```
//AnagraficRepository
public function findAddress($Id)
{
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
             ->select('r.address')
             ->where('r.id = :id')
             ->setParameter('id', $Id)
             ->getQuery();

     return $qb->getResult();
}
```

there is something wrong with this query because I do not return any value, but if I do the query normally:

```
//Controller
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBusinessBundle:Anagrafic')->find($id);
```

Return the right value.
How do I do a query selecting only one column?

Comment: My goal was to reduce the size of the query, return a single column than 30 columns is much better in terms of performance!

Comment: Then you will do it everywhere? I'd better separate your table for few another tables in this case.

Comment: I thought it was a good way to gain in performance!
If you do not agree does not matter ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are requesting single column of each record you are bound to expect an `array`. That being said you should replace `getResult` with `getArrayResult()` because you can't enforce object hydration:

```
$data = $qb->getArrayResult();
Now, you have structure:
    $data[0]['address']
    $data[1]['address']
    ....
```

Hope this helps.

As for the discussion about performance in comments I generally agree with you for not wanting all 30 column fetch every time. However, in that case, you should consider writing *named queries* in order to minimize impact if you database ever gets altered.

Comment: Really thank you very much for the help!
Is exactly the information I was looking for!

Comment: I tried `getArrayResult` and it comes out no differently than `getResult`; an index array of arrays like `['column_name'] => 'value'`. Very annoying. Symfony 3.4 so far... ah well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [partial objects](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#partial-objects) to only hydrate one field and still return a object.

Comment: Updated link: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#partial-objects

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer instead of linking to external pages

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
  $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->select('i.name')
    ->...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use partial objects like this to select fields

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ->select(array('partial r.{id,address}'))
    ...
```

Put your field names between the brackets

Comment: ...but keep in mind the documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html