# Doctrine 2. How can i get only one column from table?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this entity:

```
class TruckOrderPud {
/**
 * @ORM\Id     
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Pud")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pud_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $pudId;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TruckOrder")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="truck_order_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $truckOrderId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="package_count", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true}, nullable=true)
 */
protected $packageCount;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="package_weight", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true}, nullable=true)
 */
protected $packageWeight;
```

}

I am needing get only single column `pudId` from this entity by `truckOrderId` parameter.

I am try:

```
   $result = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT top.pudId FROM AppTruckingBundle:TruckOrderPud top WHERE top.truckOrderId = ?1')
                    ->setParameter(1, $truckOrderId)
                    ->getSQL();`
```

Then I have error:

`"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 11 near 'pudId FROM AppTruckingBundle:TruckOrderPud': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression."`

If i change query from `'SELECT top.pudId...'` on `'SELECT top...'` is it all OK.

I am also try:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('top.pudId')
                 ->from('AppTruckingBundle:TruckOrderPud', 'top')
                 ->where($qb->expr()->eq('top.truckOrderId', $truckOrderId));`
```

In this case I am getting identical error. If i change `$qb->select('top.pudId')` on `$qb->select('top')` is it all OK.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046916/symfony2-select-one-column-in-doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PudId is a foreign key that refers to Pud, so you have to refer to Pud. Try this

```
$qb->select('IDENTITY(top.pud) PudId')
->from('AppTruckingBundle:TruckOrderPud', 'top')
->where($qb->expr()->eq('top.truckOrderId', $truckOrderId));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `1` from the `?1` and leave only `?`:

```
   $result = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT top.pudId FROM AppTruckingBundle:TruckOrderPud top WHERE top.truckOrderId = ?')
                    ->setParameter(1, $truckOrderId)
                    ->getSQL();
```

Doctrine does the parameter positioning by itself (first param on the first question mark spot). Read [here](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) for details.